# jquery validate number NOT working

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate numbers but this code is not working.
When I enter character like(a, b, c) does not show error and I want to pass if only a number.

```
$(function () {
    $(".checkNumber").click(function () {
        var number = $("#number").val();
        if (number.length < 1 && !$.isNumeric(number)) {
            // show errors 
            ;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is malformed, please correct it so it's easier to help out.

Comment: "but this code is not working" What does mean???

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `or` insted of `and` in that conditional?

Comment: Use `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: Your if condition will never be true since you are checking to see if the length of the input is less than 1 AND if it is a number. The length being less than one means that there can be no value in the input, and therefore, it will never be a number.

Comment: One of these moments where a wrongly chosen boolean operator makes all the difference.

Comment: @A.Wolff As always, testing empty strings and `undefined` and `NULL` yields unexpected results. Which is probably why we have [`$.isNumeric`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) in the first place.

Comment: Considering the question (that has now been edited). He only has to remove this part `number.length < 1 && `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test just the result coming from `$.isNumeric()`.

The method handles any kind of argument passed, even empty, null, etc.

```
$(function () {
    $(".checkNumber").click(function () {
        if (!$.isNumeric($("#number").val())) {
            // Show error
        }
    });
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E9sFU/

## HTML

```
<input type="text" id="quty1" />
<div class="errorMsg"></div>

$('#quty1').keypress(function (e) {
    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error messag
        $(".errorMsg").html("Only numbers are allowed.");
        return false;
    } else {
        $(".errorMsg").html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: What will you do about exponential like 4e7 (4 raised to 7)

Answer (score -1):

Change the && with || and cast the value to integer or float to make the comparison.

```
$(function () {
    $(".checkNumber").click(function () {
        var number = $("#number").val();
        if (!$.isNumeric(number) || parseInt(number) < 1) { // or cast to float with parseFloat(number)
            // show errors
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Since when just integers are considered numbers?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: You are right, I edited my answer. Did you vote down for this??